# @font-face in an iframe in IE9

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-9, font-face

I've been struggling with an issue for days now. I have a webfont kit from fontsquirrel. IE9 won't load the fonts when I load the containing webpage in an iframe. Weirdly enough, when I load the page in the browser itself, it does work. No errors in F12 developer tools.

The code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 0 1em 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        /*overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;*/
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'bebas_neueregular';
        src: url('build/img/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?');
        src: url('build/img/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('build/img/BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('build/img/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('build/img/BebasNeue-webfont.svg#bebas_neueregular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Do you have a live sample of this issue? Any possibility of crossdomain issues, since `iframe` is in play? Have you tried to use absolute paths to your font files on the live site?